# Python Help MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, csv, automation

I am new to Python and I am looking for a solution to populate a MySQL Database with CSV files from a Local Folder.

1. I would like to do a mass import to the MySQL DB
2. When a new CSV is added to the Local Folder, it is automatically imported into the Database

Thanking you in advance

Comment: - CSV files have static schema or dynamic ? 
- Local Folder in your PC or in a server ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is filesystem events monitoring with python- you want a python program to listen to events (read, write, delete, etc..) on the filesystem and whenever there's a new file in a specific folder to write the content to MySQL.

For that, I suggest you use [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog).
watchdog is a library for listening for such events on the filesystem.
With watchdog you probably want to include some MySQL library for python and implement the reading from csv (maybe pandas library will be helpful there) and writing to the db.